# Using AWS Cognito instead of Azure AD

Tags: sharepoint-online, active-directory, azure-ad, aws

Is it possible to use AWS Cognito instead of Azure AD to authenticate users in SharePoint Online? Is there a workaround?

I didn't find anything. I could only find how to use SharePoint Online with Azure AD and Cognito. I could also find Cognito Forms.

My question is about if it is possible without Azure AD and how. A manual would be sufficient.

Best regards

Jens

Answer (score 0):

Office 365 doesn't exist without Azure AD. You cannot remove that dependency. With that being said, you're free to use other IdPs to perform authentication.

With some simple searches, I found the following that may be useful.

[Adding SAML Identity Providers to a User Pool](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-saml-idp.html)

[How to set up AWS Cognito with federation to Office365](https://www.idea11.com.au/how-to-set-up-aws-cognito-federation-office365/)

With those out of the way, [AWS SSO](https://aws.amazon.com/single-sign-on/) would be the *proper* solution for this as it is designed to act as an IdP.